# Use attribute in cart - not showing although added to config.xml

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, cart, configuration

I have a custom attribute that I want to use in the cart to show some specific output text. That's usually pretty easy, just add it to the config.xml

```
<global>
        <sales>
            <quote>
                <item>
                    <product_attributes>
                        <jr_brand />
                        <jr_preorderable />
                    </product_attributes>
                </item>
            </quote>
        </sales>
</global>
```

The first attribute was already there when I took over the project. It works fine. I added the second one. It doesn't show up. I can do a var_dump on the product, it is not there.

Does anyone know a configuration on the attributes, that could make a difference on whether these usually pretty simple lines work or not? Btw, no cache problem. If I delete the first one, it is gone in the var_dump immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem: Although i ran the indexer it seemed to not have created the flat products table correctly. Running it again did solve the problem.